# tomcat-users.xml getting reset after stopping Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

When I add a user to

> [tomcat installation]/conf/tomcat-users.xml

by adding the following:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

It works well enough, but after I stop/restart my server that little edit of mine just completely disappears and I have to redo it. Anybody know why this would happen?

Comment: do you start the tomcat from commandLine or from an eclipse ?

Comment: @ShadowRay - From *gulp Eclipse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse takes over the configuration of Tomcat,  so try  to edit `tomcat-users` from eclipse.
under the `Servers` folder in the package explorer